# How to contol the time interval in a DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a **DateTimePicker** control on a form specified like so:

```
dtpEntry.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dtpEntry.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
dtpEntry.ShowUpDown = true;
```

I would like the user to only be able to increment or decrement the time by 5 minute increments.

Any suggestions on how one would accomplish this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible by watching the ValueChanged event and override the value.  This sample form worked well:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm";
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.ShowUpDown = true;
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(DateTime.Now.Hour);
        mPrevDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        dateTimePicker1.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged);
    }
    private DateTime mPrevDate;
    private bool mBusy;

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!mBusy) {
            mBusy = true;
            DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
            if ((dt.Minute * 60 + dt.Second) % 300 != 0) {
                TimeSpan diff = dt - mPrevDate;
                if (diff.Ticks < 0) dateTimePicker1.Value = mPrevDate.AddMinutes(-5);
                else dateTimePicker1.Value = mPrevDate.AddMinutes(5);
            }
            mBusy = false;
        }
        mPrevDate = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked perfectly, all I needed to do was adjust the value in `AddMinutes()` for my case and it was literally plug and play.

Answer (score 8):

I've changed a little the answer from SixOThree, to eliminate the bug found by Necromporph. 
It should be ok like this:

in the class

```
private DateTime prevTimePicker1;
private bool navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
```

in the constructor

```
prevTimePicker1 = dateTimePickerStart.Value;
navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
```

the event

```
private void dateTimePickerStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!navigatingDateTimePicker) {
    /* First set the navigating flag to true so this method doesn't get called again while updating */
    navigatingDateTimePicker = true;

    /* using timespan because that's the only way I know how to round times well */
    TimeSpan tempTS = dateTimePickerStart.Value - dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date;
    TimeSpan roundedTimeSpan;

    TimeSpan TDBug = dateTimePickerStart.Value - prevTimePicker1;
    if (TDBug.TotalMinutes == 59)
    {
        // first: if we are going back and skipping an hour it needs an adjustment
        roundedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5 * Math.Floor((tempTS.TotalMinutes - 60) / 5));
        dateTimePickerStart.Value = dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date + roundedTimeSpan;
    }
    else if (dateTimePickerStart.Value > prevTimePicker1)
    {
        // round up to the nearest interval
        roundedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5 * Math.Ceiling(tempTS.TotalMinutes / 5));
        dateTimePickerStart.Value = dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date + roundedTimeSpan;
    } else {
        // round down to the nearest interval from prev
        roundedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5 * Math.Floor(tempTS.TotalMinutes / 5));
        dateTimePickerStart.Value = dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date + roundedTimeSpan;
    }
    navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
  }
  prevTimePicker1 = dateTimePickerStart.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or simply try this:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Minute % 5 == 0)
        return;

    if (this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Minute % 5 == 1)
        this.dateTimePicker1.Value = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(4);

    if (this.dateTimePicker1.Value.Minute % 5 == 4)
        this.dateTimePicker1.Value = this.dateTimePicker1.Value.AddMinutes(-4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the up/down control automatically increments or decrements the currently highlighted portion of the date/time picker (i.e. year/month/day/hour/etc.).

You are probably better off adding your own up/down control (perhaps a very small vscrollbar) immediately adjacent to the date/time picker and wiring it up to increment/decrement five minute intervals from the date/time picker's value.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old article, but I created a better solution to this problem based on the answer above.

in the class

```
private DateTime prevTimePicker1;
private bool navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
```

in the constructor

```
prevTimePicker1 = dateTimePickerStart.Value;
navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
```

the event

```
private void dateTimePickerStart_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!navigatingDateTimePicker) {
    /* First set the navigating flag to true so this method doesn't get called again while updating */
    navigatingDateTimePicker = true;

    /* using timespan because that's the only way I know how to round times well */
    TimeSpan tempTS = dateTimePickerStart.Value - dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date;
    TimeSpan roundedTimeSpan;

    if (dateTimePickerStart.Value > prevTimePicker1) {
      // round up to the nearest interval
      roundedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5 * Math.Ceiling(tempTS.TotalMinutes / 5));
      dateTimePickerStart.Value = dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date + roundedTimeSpan;
    } else {
      // round down to the nearest interval from prev
      roundedTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5 * Math.Floor(tempTS.TotalMinutes / 5));
      dateTimePickerStart.Value = dateTimePickerStart.Value.Date + roundedTimeSpan;
    }
    navigatingDateTimePicker = false;
  }
  prevTimePicker1 = dateTimePickerStart.Value;
}
```

Comment: I like your answer SixOThree, but i tried to use it, and it works great going up, up works like a charm. But if you go down it once it gets to "00" it start making the hours go up. im trying to find why as we speak. Once this one bug is fixed, im sure this will be awesome functionality.

Answer (score 0):

you could add this code

```
int minuteDiff = dtpJamAppointmentDokter.Value.Minute - prevTimePicker1.Minute;

if (minuteDiff == 59)
{
    dtpJamAppointmentDokter.Value =  dtpJamAppointmentDokter.Value.AddHours(-1);
}
```

before

```
TimeSpan tempTS = dtpJamAppointmentDokter.Value - dtpJamAppointmentDokter.Value.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Hans Passant Just needed to handle 59 for it to work right.

```
private void dateTimePickerReportScheduleTime_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         if (!mBusy)
         {
             mBusy = true;
             DateTime dt = dateTimePickerReportScheduleTime.Value;
             if ((dt.Minute * 60 + dt.Second) % 300 != 0)
             {
                 TimeSpan diff = dt - mPrevDate;
                 if (dt.Minute == 59) 
                 { 
                     dateTimePickerReportScheduleTime.Value = mPrevDate.AddMinutes(-15); 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if (diff.Ticks < 0) dateTimePickerReportScheduleTime.Value = mPrevDate.AddMinutes(-15);
    
                     else dateTimePickerReportScheduleTime.Value = mPrevDate.AddMinutes(15);
                 }
             }
             mBusy = false;
         }
         mPrevDate = dateTimePickerReportScheduleTime.Value;
     }
```