# DateTimePicker - Which subfield has focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a class that derives from `DateTimePicker`. The picker control has format set to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom` and custom format string set to `yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm` in order to display dates in the format `2013.01.25 21:45`. Here, `2013` is the year subfield that gets highlited when the users clicks on it with the mouse cursor or tabs to it using the `TAB` key. Once highlited, the user can use `UP`/`DOWN` keys to increment / decrement the year, or manually enter a new year value. The same holds true for the month, day, hour and minute subfields.

For my application, certain dates or time values are forbidden. For instance, consider the following rule:

- An appointment can only be scheduled at a time rounded to the nearest 10 minutes. For instance, you can schedule one at either 21:10 or 21:20, not at 21:13.

For this, I need to know which subfield currently has focus. The problem is I don't know how to determine this. If I know which subfield has focus, I could devise the following set of rules in code.

- If the minute subfield is selected, and the user presses the `UP` key, increment the time by 10 minutes.
- If the minute subfield is selected, and the user presses the `DOWN` key, decrement the time by 10 minutes.
- If the minute subfield has lost focus, round the minutes up or down to the nearest 10 minutes.

The only problem that remains.. **HOW DO I FIND WHICH SUBFIELD CURRENTLY HAS FOCUS?**

NOTE: Yes I can make validation checks in `OnLeave` event but the my application requires that invalid datetime values be skipped altogether. Also, I have checked out the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846068/how-to-contol-the-time-interval-in-a-datetimepicker?rq=1). But I am inclined to find the active subfield as an exercise as well. Finally, if its of any use, I'm using C# 4.0 on Windows 7 x86.

Comment: I've never seen anything about the stock DateTimePicker that suggests you can access the sub-controls in it. Why is the linked answer not sufficient? It appears to exactly fit your requirements.

Comment: solution: WPF. Another Solution: DevExpress, which already does the up/down and mouse wheel stuff (even the winforms one, I think)

Comment: @kettch. Well, I want to see if it's actually possible as an exercise. I am deriving from the `DateTimePicker` control. All functionality should be available to me. Even if its not public, I should be able to use reflection to access non-public code.

Comment: @kettch. Also, the solution presented in the link causes the field to lose focus everytime the value is corrected.

Comment: I think that if you do a select (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.select(v=vs.110).aspx) on the control, it gets focused with the previously selected element. You could run the code from that other solution and then do dtp.Select(), and it should get the effect that you want. It's not necessarily elegant, but I don't think there's a way to do it from any exposed API's.