# Adapting Powershell Forms script with C# algorithm

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to adapt [this Powershell script](https://meneerb.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/time-frame-picker-powershell/), with [this C# algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846068/how-to-contol-the-time-interval-in-a-datetimepicker).  I actually want 15 minute intervals, so I modified the C# algorithm a bit, and perhaps made it a bit more flexible.  I believe many of the issues I'm running in to are variable scoping issues...

I did this initially from the Powershell ISE (which kept crashing over and over again!)... this is a modification of the [Powershell script](https://meneerb.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/time-frame-picker-powershell/) to try to incorporate the [C# algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846068/how-to-contol-the-time-interval-in-a-datetimepicker)...

```
    # ShiftEndTimePicker
$ShiftEndTimePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$ShiftEndTimePicker.Location = “200, 42”
$ShiftEndTimePicker.Width = “175”
$ShiftEndTimePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$ShiftEndTimePicker.CustomFormat = “h:mm tt”
$ShiftEndTimePicker.Value = "8:15 AM"
$ShiftEndTimePicker.ShowUpDown = $TRUE
$ShiftEndPrevTime = $ShiftEndTimePicker.Value
$pso = new-object psobject -property @{ ShiftEndPrevTime = $ShiftEndPrevTime }
# $pso = new-object psobject -property @{ ShiftEndPrevTime = $ShiftEndPrevTime; ShiftEndTimePicker = $ShiftEndTimePicker }
$job = Register-ObjectEvent -inputObject $ShiftEndTimePicker -eventName ValueChanged `
                            -sourceIdentifier ShiftEndTimePicker.Interval `
                            -MessageData $pso `
                            -Action {
    Write-Host "event.MessageData.ShiftEndPrevTime: $($event.MessageData.ShiftEndPrevTime)"
    $ShiftEndInterval = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15
    if (-Not $ShiftEndBusy)
    {
        $ShiftEndBusy = $TRUE
        [DateTime]$dtShiftEnd = $Sender.Value
        if (($dtShiftEnd.Minute * 60 + $dtShiftEnd.Second) % $ShiftEndInterval.TotalSeconds -ne 0)
        {
            [TimeSpan]$diff = $dtShiftEnd - $event.MessageData.ShiftEndPrevTime
            if ($diff.Ticks -lt 0) { $Sender.Value = $event.MessageData.ShiftEndPrevTime.AddTicks(- $ShiftEndInterval.Ticks) }
            else { $Sender.Value = $event.MessageData.ShiftEndPrevTime.AddTicks($ShiftEndInterval.Ticks) }
            <#
            if ($diff.Ticks -lt 0) { ($event.MessageData.ShiftEndTimePicker).Value = $event.MessageData.ShiftEndPrevTime.AddTicks(- $ShiftEndInterval.Ticks) }
            else { ($event.MessageData.ShiftEndTimePicker).Value = $event.MessageData.ShiftEndPrevTime.AddTicks($ShiftEndInterval.Ticks) }
            #>
        }
        $ShiftEndBusy = $FALSE
    }
    [Datetime]$event.MessageData.ShiftEndPrevTime = $Sender.Value
    Write-Host "sender.Value: $($Sender.Value)"
}
Receive-Job $job
$mainForm.Controls.Add($ShiftEndTimePicker)
```

but I believe that the datetimepicker sent in by the Register-ObjectEvent statement, $ShiftEndTimePicker, is being sent into the Action script by value, so when I make a change to $Sender.Value in the Action script it doesn't change the value of the DateTime object in the $ShiftEndTimePicker datetimepicker in the broader scope in the displayed $ShiftEndTimePicker datetimepicker is displayed to the user?

I also tried this in Powershell Studio, which appears perhaps to be suggesting that it's handling some of the event handling stuff as C# and Visual Studio appear to be doing behind the scenes that I don't believe Powershell is doing for us...

```
$form1_Load={
    #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here
    $ShiftEndTimePicker.Location = "200, 42"
    $ShiftEndTimePicker.Width = "175"
    $ShiftEndTimePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
    $ShiftEndTimePicker.CustomFormat = "h:mm tt"
    $ShiftEndTimePicker.Value = "8:15 AM"
    $ShiftEndTimePicker.ShowUpDown = $TRUE
    $ShiftEndPrevTime = $ShiftEndTimePicker.Value
}

[DateTime]$ShiftEndPrevTime = $ShiftEndTimePicker.Value
[Bool]$ShiftEndBusy
Write-Host "ShiftEndPrevTime: $($ShiftEndPrevTime)"


$ShiftEndTimePicker_ValueChanged = {
    #TODO: Place custom script here
    $ShiftEndInterval = New-TimeSpan -Minutes 15
    if (-Not $ShiftEndBusy)
    {
        $ShiftEndBusy = $TRUE
        [DateTime]$dtShiftEnd = $ShiftEndTimePicker.Value
        Write-Host "dtShiftEnd: $($dtShiftEnd)"
        Write-Host "ShiftEndTimePicker.Value: $($ShiftEndTimePicker.Value)"
        Write-Host "ShiftEndPrevTime: $($ShiftEndPrevTime)"
        if (($dtShiftEnd.Minute * 60 + $dtShiftEnd.Second) % $ShiftEndInterval.TotalSeconds -ne 0)
        {
            [TimeSpan]$diff = $dtShiftEnd - $ShiftEndPrevTime
            if ($diff.Ticks -lt 0) { $ShiftEndTimePicker.Value = $ShiftEndPrevTime.AddTicks(- $ShiftEndInterval.Ticks) }
            else { $ShiftEndTimePicker.Value = $ShiftEndPrevTime.AddTicks($ShiftEndInterval.Ticks) }
        }
        $ShiftEndBusy = $FALSE
    }
    [Datetime]$ShiftEndPrevTime = $ShiftEndTimePicker.Value
}
```

Similarly, I believe there are variable scoping issues here as well, but I'm just lost at this point.  If I try to declare a null datetime, like in the C#... here... [DateTime]$ShiftEndPrevTime... apparently, in the same block of the program as in the C#, Powershell throws an error.  It appears Powershell doesn't like a null DateTime object.  Perhaps in C# the variable mPrevDate is in the same scope of the mPrevDate in the Form1 block above?

I'm just kinda lost and frustrated.  Can someone point me down some path forward here?  Thanks.

Comment: BTW, my answer below came from [Event-Handling on Powershell-GUI (System.Windows.Forms)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b12ad0b9-ccd2-4c86-9a1c-a07fdab6605f/eventhandling-on-powershellgui-systemwindowsforms?forum=winserverpowershell). The answerer there said **_"Don't use the PowerShell register-objectevent as it will not work in the way that you think it would. It is going to be fighting the UI for the thread and never actually fire"_**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to get `Register-ObjectEvent` to work, but you can program events on the `minPicker` and `maxPicker` controls directly.

I took your #1 script [(Meneer's 'Time Frame Picker Powershell' script)](https://meneerb.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/time-frame-picker-powershell/) and added code to set ValueChanged events for the minPicker and the maxPicker. Then, I added an event `Label` and event `TextBox` and I use the event `TextBox` just to prove that the events are firing.

I ran and tested this program on a Windows 10 machine using PowerShell 5 and it works.

See the two new functions at the top and the two uses of .Add_ValueChanged for the `minPicker` and `maxPicker` controls

You have to write the code inside my functions `OnMaxTimePicker_ValueChanged` and `OnMaxTimePicker_ValueChanged` to make the time increments work like you want

```
###########################################################
# TimeFramePicker.ps1
#
# MeneerB 29/07/2015
###########################################################
cls

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

#Function added by NovaSysEng: Executed when the ValueChanged event fires on the maxPicker control
function OnMaxTimePicker_ValueChanged
{
    $eventTextBox.Text = "max time changed"
}

#Function added by NovaSysEng: Executed when the ValueChanged event fires on the minPicker control
function OnMinTimePicker_ValueChanged
{
    $eventTextBox.Text = "min time changed"
}

# Main Form
$mainForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font(“Consolas”, 13)
$mainForm.Text = ” Pick Time Frame”
$mainForm.Font = $font
$mainForm.ForeColor = “White”
$mainForm.BackColor = “DarkOliveGreen”
$mainForm.Width = 300
$mainForm.Height = 250
$mainForm.Location.X = 600

# DatePicker Label
$datePickerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$datePickerLabel.Text = “date”
$datePickerLabel.Location = “15, 10”
$datePickerLabel.Height = 22
$datePickerLabel.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($datePickerLabel)

# MinTimePicker Label
$minTimePickerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$minTimePickerLabel.Text = “min-time”
$minTimePickerLabel.Location = “15, 45”
$minTimePickerLabel.Height = 22
$minTimePickerLabel.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($minTimePickerLabel)

# MaxTimePicker Label
$maxTimePickerLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$maxTimePickerLabel.Text = “max-time”
$maxTimePickerLabel.Location = “15, 80”
$maxTimePickerLabel.Height = 22
$maxTimePickerLabel.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($maxTimePickerLabel)

# Event Label (Added by NovaSysEng just to show how the events are firing)
$eventLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$eventLabel.Text = “event”
$eventLabel.Location = “15, 120”
$eventLabel.Height = 22
$eventLabel.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($eventLabel)

# Event text box (Added by NovaSysEng just to show how the events are firing)
$eventTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$eventTextBox.Text = “n/a”
$eventTextBox.Location = “110, 120”
$eventTextBox.Height = 22
$eventTextBox.Width = 90
$mainForm.Controls.Add($eventTextBox)

# DatePicker
$datePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$datePicker.Location = “110, 7”
$datePicker.Width = “150”
$datePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$datePicker.CustomFormat = “dd/MM/yyyy”
$mainForm.Controls.Add($datePicker)

# MinTimePicker
$minTimePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$minTimePicker.Location = “110, 42”
$minTimePicker.Width = “150”
$minTimePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$minTimePicker.CustomFormat = “HH:mm:ss”
$minTimePicker.ShowUpDown = $TRUE
# Added by NovaSysEng: Add ValueChanged Event to the minPicker control
$minTimePicker.Add_ValueChanged({OnMinTimePicker_ValueChanged})
$mainForm.Controls.Add($minTimePicker)

# MaxTimePicker
$maxTimePicker = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker
$maxTimePicker.Location = “110, 77”
$maxTimePicker.Width = “150”
$maxTimePicker.Format = [windows.forms.datetimepickerFormat]::custom
$maxTimePicker.CustomFormat = “HH:mm:ss”
$maxTimePicker.ShowUpDown = $TRUE
# Added by NovaSysEng: Add ValueChanged Event  to the maxPicker control
$maxTimePicker.Add_ValueChanged({OnMaxTimePicker_ValueChanged})
$mainForm.Controls.Add($maxTimePicker)

# OK Button
$okButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$okButton.Location = “15, 170”
$okButton.ForeColor = “Black”
$okButton.BackColor = “White”
$okButton.Text = “OK”
$okButton.add_Click({$mainForm.close()})
$mainForm.Controls.Add($okButton)

[void] $mainForm.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll try that.

Comment: Yes, it works!  I just tested it.  The datetime value for the datetimepicker control in the main program on the mainform is changing now!  Thank you!

Comment: @Paul: Glad it worked - Doing WInForms using PowerShell is a bit of a challenge