# How to make DateTimePicker not editable through user typing

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker in my windows forms and I have it To pick the time for a certain event in my program in the form HH:mm.

```
private void TimePicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DateTime dt = TimeEndPicker.Value;
  int mins = dt.Minute;
  if (mins == 1 || mins == 31)
  {
    dt = dt.AddMinutes(29);
    TimeEndPicker.Value = dt;
  }
  else if (mins == 59 || mins == 29)
  {
    dt = dt.AddMinutes(-29);
    TimeEndPicker.Value = dt;
  }
}
```

It works well for when the user clicks on the up and down buttons but if the user selects and types it doesn't work as intended as it usually wont be 1,31,29,59.

I think the easiest way to fix this would be to only allow the user to press the buttons and not let the value be editable by typing but am not sure if this is possible? any help would be appreciated. desired result being only being able to pick half an hour intervals.

Comment: Are you looking to round the entered time to the nearest 30 minutes?

Comment: yes my bad will edit the question to make clearer

Comment: Consider adding a `Validating` event handler

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846068/how-to-contol-the-time-interval-in-a-datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had a bit of a ponder about this and I hit upon an idea that works reasonably well in this case:

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Up)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Tag = string.Empty;
            dateTimePicker1.Value += TimeSpan.FromMinutes(14.5);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Down)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Tag = string.Empty;
            dateTimePicker1.Value -= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(14.5);
        }
    }

    private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dateTimePicker1.Tag == string.Empty)
        {
            dateTimePicker1.Tag = null;
            return;
        }

        dateTimePicker1.Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date.AddMinutes(
            Math.Round(dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalMinutes / 30, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * 30
        );
    }
```

Setting the Tag to something is a debounce/indicator that the code should ignore the ValueChanged event. You could do the same with a boolean, it just saves adding another field to the class. If the Tag is set to something, then ValueChanged unsets it and exits. If it's not set then the Value in the dtp is rounded to the nearest 30 minutes by "take the date, and add to it the number of minutes given by (minutes divide 30, round, times 30) i.e. a standard "round to the nearest X" algorithm. We use AwayFromZero otherwise 15 minutes rounds down and 45 minutes rounds up

The KeyDown event is where it gets a bit more trick:

- **If the user focuses the *minutes*** and presses UP then the keydown adds 14.5 minutes and sets the Tag. ValueChanged fires and unsets the tag. The KeyUp completes and the dtp adds **one more minute** to itself. ValueChanged fires *again*. A total of 15.5 minutes have been added, causing the time to round UP to the next 30 minutes interval. 17:00 became 17:14:30 (no rounding was done) became 17:15:30 and rounding was done to result in 17:30. **17:00 became 17:30**

  - A similar thing occurs if you press DOWN; a total of 15.5 minutes decrement rounds down to the next earlier 30 minute
- **If the user focuses the *hours*** and presses UP then the keydown adds 14.5 minutes and sets the Tag. ValueChanged fires and unsets the tag. The KeyUp completes and the dtp adds **one hour** to itself. ValueChanged fires *again*. A total of 1 hour and 14.5 minutes have been added, causing the time to round DOWN to the same 30 *minutes* interval it was already on, so the only thing that ended up changing is the *hour*. 17:00 became 17:14:30 (no rounding was done) became 18:14:30 and rounding was done to result in 18:00. **17:00 became 18:00**

  - A similar thing occurs if you press DOWN; a total of 1h 14.5m decrement, which rounds up 14.5m to the next earlier hour
- **If the user *types a time*** it simplistically rounds to the nearest 30 minute interval. 17:14 rounds to 17:00, and 17:15 rounds to 17:30

<sub>The only thing I would say, with this technique is that the up down buttons don't work as expected - the simplest thing is to hide them so they aren't clicked on; put the dtp inside a panel, align the top left corners and make the panel narrower than the dtp is</sub>